# in ASP.NET how can I set the current User Identity for the session?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I've got a simple page, and I have a login button.  I simply want to programmatically set the User identity so that when I re-navigate to this page or any other I can get the current User identity. Are there special considerations for this?

Comment: Are you using [`FormsAuthentication`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xdt4thhy.aspx)?

Comment: I have no idea honestly.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Short Answer:

```
//
// Swapped FormsIdentity principal with our own custom IPrincipal
//
HttpContext.Current.User = yourPrincipalFromSomewhere;

//see
//http://www.hanselman.com/blog/SystemThreadingThreadCurrentPrincipalVsSystemWebHttpContextCurrentUserOrWhyFormsAuthenticationCanBeSubtle.aspx

//
// Sync Context Principal with Thread Principal
//
System.Threading.Thread.CurrentPrincipal = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User;
```

So on the login, my team would put the IPrincipal (our custom one) here:

```
HttpContext.Current.Cache.Insert
```

And then on in the

```
        protected void Application_AuthenticateRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
}
```

we would grab it from the :

```
HttpContext.Current.Cache
```

and then reattach it to the :

```
// Swapped FormsIdentity principal with our own IPrincipal
                            //
                            HttpContext.Current.User = cachedPrincipal;

                            //see
                            //http://www.hanselman.com/blog/SystemThreadingThreadCurrentPrincipalVsSystemWebHttpContextCurrentUserOrWhyFormsAuthenticationCanBeSubtle.aspx

                            //
                            // Sync Context Principal with Thread Principal
                            //
                            System.Threading.Thread.CurrentPrincipal = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User;
```

Am I saying "do it exactly like my team did"?  Not necessarily.
But I'm showing you the 2 places we came across to attach it.

And the hanselman link, which shows some info about it.

http://www.hanselman.com/blog/SystemThreadingThreadCurrentPrincipalVsSystemWebHttpContextCurrentUserOrWhyFormsAuthenticationCanBeSubtle.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Save userId:

```
Session["UserId"] = loggedInUserId;
```

Retrieve userId

```
int loggedInUserId  = (int)Session["UserId"];
```

What kind of special considerations are you worried about? Be more specific.

Comment: I'm wondering if there is a more standard way of doing this and if I should be leveraging the Page.User property of type System.Security.Principal.IPrincipal?

Comment: Generally speaking, storing user data in session is the least preferred option.

Comment: @StingyJack is right. @Firoso, why do you even need to access UserId? Usually all you need to know is if a user is authenticated. For that you can use 'FormsAuthentication' to log person in and then check if he's logged in by [Authenticate] attribute on the actions or `@User.Identity.IsAuthenticated` in the views.

Comment: @StingyJack care to Elaborate?

Comment: Dmitry, I do need to know what user is logged in to access their associated data.

Comment: Like everything, they have a purpose. Session variables store user data on your server at the cost of server memory, so if its only a little bit of data and a few users, its probably fine, but too much can run your server out of memory. Session vars are not typesafe, so you may get runtime errors when casting values from it.Also, ASP.NET has many other fine replacements if you need to store user data (profile provider, cache, viewstate, etc).

Comment: Also take a look at http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/160947/should-session-variables-be-avoided

Comment: Okay StingyJack, what then do you propose?

Comment: @Firoso you will have to do a little bit of research on forms authentication, memberships, IPrinciple, IIdentity etc. I just gave out a few words you can google. you need to do the research. Not sure if this [link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/796940/Understanding-Using-and-Customizing-ASP-NET-Identi) will help but give it a try.